# Drupal Cache corruption

Tags: drupal, wsod

I am running Drupal 6.22 and very occasionally (every few months) I get a White Screen on Death. (WSOD).

I find clearing the cache with "drush cc all" solves the problem, but what could be the route cause?

Comment: Check the logs. WSOD almost always means a PHP error in your webserver's log.

Comment: No errors in the web server (apache) log files - This was the first thing I checked

Comment: What about the Drupal database logs?

Comment: Nothing in the Drupal DB logs either (http://site-admin/admin/reports/dblog), EXCEPT the following - which is probably another issue.  These occur constantly, even when there is no WSOD.


Unknown column &#039;node_data_field_event_start.field_event_start_value&#039; in &#039;where clause&#039; query: SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid, node.type AS node_type FROM node node INNER JOIN node_access na ON na.nid = node.nid WHERE (na.grant_view &gt;= 1 AND ((na.gid = 0 AND